# while compiling my c++ project under Centos I get an error saying "cannot find -ltinyxml"

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, c++11, gcc

When I try to compile my eclipse project(c++) on CentOS, it comes up with an error saying "cannot find -ltinyxml"

I tried changing the cross GCC compiler command from "g++ -std=c++11" to "g++ -std=c++0x"

If I keep the command as "g++ -std=c++11" I am getting an error that says:-

cclplus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [util/Bool.o] Error 1

I tried searching and found out that the command should be  "g++ -std=c++0x"
I tried this one and now I'm not getting the same error, instead I get "cannot find -ltinyxml"

To add more information, it's CentOS 64 bit (Via VBox) and I am running Eclipse neon 2, have installed CDT features as well.
I have also installed gcc using "yum install gcc-c++"

Lemme know if more information is required.

Comment: Did you install libtinyxml in your cross build environment?

Comment: No I didn't, let me try that once

Comment: Do I need to install mysql-workbench for it as "yum install libtinyxml" is not working

Comment: Check there what's needed: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/

Comment: Ok, it was yum install tinyxml

Comment: You my friend, are a legend, it worked and issue is fixed!!! yay!!! Cheers!!